# java 1.8+ Full-Screen Exclusive Mode setFullScreenWindow(Frame) strange behavior

Tags: java, fullscreen

I'm working on a fullscreen application and discovered some really weird behavior using `setFullScreenWindow(Frame)` to actually get the application frame to fullscreen exclusive mode on some notebooks. While my code works on most WinOS systems on some it just doesn't. The resolution change works but the application stays in the top left corner of the screen in its former resolution like the `setFullScreenWindow(Frame)` call did not actually work. No exception thrown. If I connect a second display to the system and make it primary display it suddenly works. If I disconnect the second display and run the app on the previous used native display it also now suddenly works. If I reboot the system the native display again fails to bring the app to fullscreen. Both `isFullScreenSupported()` and `isDisplayChangeSupported()` are true in any cases.
Strange. Notebook is a MacBookPro with a Bootcamp WinOS10 installation but problem is not limited to this hardware or WinOsVersion.

```
            client.windowScale = 2;
            client.setVisible(false);
            client.setResizable(false);
            client.setUndecorated(true);
            client.setSize(RES_WIDTH * client.windowScale, RES_HEIGHT * client.windowScale);

            DisplayMode newDisplayMode;
            GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
            DisplayMode_Old = gd.getDisplayMode();

            if (gd.isFullScreenSupported() & gd.isDisplayChangeSupported()) {
                gd.setFullScreenWindow(client);
                gd.setDisplayMode(
                    new DisplayMode(
                        RES_WIDTH * client.windowScale,
                        RES_HEIGHT * client.windowScale,
                        DisplayMode_Old.getBitDepth(),
                        DisplayMode_Old.getRefreshRate()));

            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Fullscreen failed.");
            }
        }
```

Actual Image: [image: Fullscreen fail]

Comment: why don't you set it in Manifest?

Comment: because I want to be able to switch between fullscreen and window mode at any time ..